# How do we stop a SharePoint 2013 workflow (Azure workflow) programmatically?

Tags: workflow, 2013

Our custom code starts the workflow using classes in the *Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices* namespace but we can't seem to find a method to end the workflow.

Your help and time is greatly appreciated. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use the server side OM (what you reference in your post), use the CSOM implementation as it's going to work both in an on-prem & Office 365 option. What you need to do is get a reference to the specific instance you want to work with.

You first need a reference to the instance service and then pass in the ID of the list & list item to see all instances, like this:

```
// connect to the workflow services via a CSOM client context
var clientContext = new ClientContext(siteCollectionUrl);
var workflowServicesManager = new WorkflowServicesManager(clientContext, clientContext.Web);

// connect to the instance service
var workflowInstanceService = workflowServicesManager.GetWorkflowInstanceService();

// get all instances
var workflowInstances = workflowInstanceService.EnumerateInstancesForListItem(listId, listItemId);
clientContext.Load(workflowInstances);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

From there, you can enumerate each of them and find the one you want to suspend or terminate:

```
foreach (var instance in workflowInstances)
{
  // is this what we are looking for?
  // ...

  // if so, suspend it
  workflowInstanceService.SuspendWorkflow(instance);

  // or you can terminate it
  workflowInstanceService.TerminateWorkflow(instance);
}
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, sorry I missed this reply previously. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

I can remember that I did it some time before (where were possibilities not only to cancel workflow, but also to suspend and resume), but I could not find my solution for a while. If it is not so urgent, I can try to find some time tomorrow to do that again.

Comment: Hi Mikhail, yes please. Or actually even just online references (if any) will be of big help already. Batiste at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/c7d9301a-3784-4241-92cf-7693a9167d3d has suggested looking at the _WorkflowInstanceService_ class.

Comment: Hi Celbester. I had a lot of work and have completely forgotten that wanted to help you. Sorry for that! Is the question still actual?

Answer (score -1):

A second way is to use the workflow client via this blog post:

http://blogs.architectingconnectedsystems.com/blogs/cjg/archive/2013/12/03/HowTo_3A00_-Terminate-all-SharePoint-2013-workflows.aspx

Comment: Can you please extend your answer with more details, if the link breaks your answer will not be very useful right now :)